# Knockoutjs! how to enable observable for INPUTs only when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend

How to enable observable for INPUTs only when checkbox is checked ?

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: booleanValue" />    
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
```

**JS:**

```
function AppViewModel() {
   booleanValue = ko.observable(true);
   this.firstName = ko.observable();
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: You need to use custom binding for deactive http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`enable`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) binding. It should do what you want.

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName, enable: booleanValue" />
```

And don't forget to add `this` when adding fields to your ViewModel (otherwise, you're creating a global variable) :

```
this.booleanValue = ko.observable(true);
```

Tell me if this helps.

**Update**

Since you precised your question in the comments, here is how you would switch between different observables (or simply values) when the box is checked :

```
<input data-bind="value: booleanValue() ? firstName : otherValue" />
```

Comment: what do you mean, "deactivate observable" ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: I need that if checkbox cheked value 1 field equated the value of another field

Comment: Thank you very much! Happy New Year!